# Can't figure out this formula in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, formula, generic-list

Sorry, I am new to coding and I can't figure this out after trying everything! I have 6 masked text boxes which the user inputs decibel values, is supposed to save them to a list, input each into a formula and output a summed decibel value, but it is simply taking the variable added as 6, which is the count of the list instead of the actual values. When I tried a foreach loop, it made it an infinite loop.

```
private void dBAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        List<double> addDBList = new List<double>();
        double final;
        double added = 0;

        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB1.Text)));
        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB2.Text)));
        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB3.Text)));
        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB4.Text)));
        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB5.Text)));
        addDBList.Add(double.Parse((dB6.Text))); 

            for (int i = 0; i < addDBList.Count; i++)
           {
            added += Math.Pow(10, (i / 10));
           }

        final = 10 * Math.Log10(added);

        totaldB.Text = final.ToString();                  
    }
```

}

The formula is basically `10log[10^(first value/10)+10^(second value/10)...+10^(nth value/10)]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
added += Math.Pow(10, (i / 10));
```

This is your problem. `i` is the index position of the array, not the actual value. You want to use this:

```
added += Math.Pow(10, (addDBList[i] / 10));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
added += Math.Pow(10, (addDBList[i] / 10));
```

Answer (score 3):

i is an integer and it ranges from 0 through 5. You're dividing that integer by 10, and as we all know, integer division doesn't have fractions, so i / 10 is always 0. In essence your inner loop is this:

```
added += Math.Pow(10, 0);
```

which is 1. Which is why added is ending up as 6.

You probably meant this instead:

```
added += Math.Pow(10, addDBList[i] / 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could (and should) use a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (double decibel in addDBList)
{
   added += Math.Pow(10, (decibel / 10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access values in Arrays or Lists you have to use the index and the identfier:

```
added += Math.Pow(10, (addDBList[i] / 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
added += Math.Pow(10, (i / 10));
```

to

```
added += Math.Pow(10, addDBList[i] / 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is the problem... replace it by

```
 for (int i = 0; i < addDBList.Count; i++)
       {
        added += Math.Pow(10, ( addDBList[i] / 10));
       }
```